# Cannot run command as www-data using su

Tags: debian, su

```
# su -l www-data ./http-app.py
This account is currently not available.
# su -l www-data -c ./http-app.py
This account is currently not available.
# su -c ./http-app.py www-data 
This account is currently not available.
# su -lc ./http-app.py www-data 
This account is currently not available.
# getent passwd www-data 
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
# getent shadow www-data 
www-data:*:16842:0:99999:7:::
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:        8.6
Codename:       jessie
```

What's wrong with my `su` or `www-data`? It used to work...

Presumably this is because of the `/usr/sbin/nologin`, but how then I drop `root` for this one script, without compromising other services on the system (`nologin` has been chosen by `Debian` team for a good reason, I want to believe)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Without debating `su` vs. `sudo` you can try adding `-s /bin/sh` to your command line. (I could not verify this option is available for jessie since the Debian manpages webserver isn't working: https://manpages.debian.org/)

Comment: Thanks, it works in Debian 9 `su www-data -s /bin/sh` to get back to root just type `su`.

Comment: @PJBrunet - "to get back to root" (assuming you su'd from root) you would type "exit". To start a new root shell you would type su.

Comment: I had to do `sudo su www-data -s /bin/sh` (or /bin/bash)

Answer (score 66):

You are using `su` which is used to "switch user". Of course it won't work because `www-data` is a user account which cannot be used to login. You have told it: `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Maybe what you want is `sudo` which is used to "execute a command as another user".

```
sudo -u www-data ./http-app.py
```

Comment: I always used `su` for this purpose and it always used to work. `sudo` is an extra package to install, but you are right, I can use it to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 17):

If you want not only execute one command, but switch to `www-data` in order to test some stuff for that user, this worked for me:

```
sudo -u www-data sh
```

It's a little bit shorter. Exit the session with [ctrl]+[d] or `exit`

Comment: Tested working too with `sudo -u www-data bash`.  Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

With this kind of problem I have used the option `-p` :

```
su -pc ./http-app.py www-data
```

-p : the environment is preserved. In peculiar it does not try to login with the new account, so you dont get the message: `This account is currently not available.` .

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility (works for me with Debian 10):

As root you can edit `/etc/passwd`. Change the shell for `www-data` from `/usr/sbin/nologin` to `/bin/bash` or whatever you prefer:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

Don't forget to give `www-data` a password with

```
passwd www-data
```

After that you can login with `www-data` as a normal user.

Comment: This is possible, but **not secure**. I do **not recommend** doing this on a production environment.